# Getting a logic error while trying to get the average of a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In this program, I have to fill a 2D array with user-inputted values and find the average of all the array's elements. However, the program instead finds the average by dividing the sum by the number of rows instead of the number of numbers. I tried setting average to a 2D array in itself but it only recognized one reference instead of both of them. Halp

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = createArray();

    System.out.printf("The average of this array is " + "%.2f", average(array));
}

public static int[][] createArray() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
    int numRows = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
    int numColumns = sc.nextInt();

    int[][] array = new int[numRows][numColumns];

    System.out.println("Enter " + array.length + " rows and " + array[0].length + " columns");

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++)
            array[row][column] = sc.nextInt();
    return array;
}

public static double average(int[][] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < a[row].length; column++) {
            sum += a[row][column];
        }
            average = sum / a.length; 
    }

    return average;
}
```

}

Comment: a is an array of arrays, so its length is the number of arrays it contains. Instead I'd suggest set count to 0 and count++ each time you get a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
> for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
>     for (int column = 0; column < a[row].length; column++) {
>         sum += a[row][column];
>     }
>         average = sum / a.length; 
> }
> ```

The issue is that you are *re-assigning* `average` on every iteration through the loop. Instead, you should calculate it after all of the loops are done:

```
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < a[row].length; column++) {
        sum += a[row][column];
    }
}

average = (double) sum / (a.length * a[0].length);
```

The product `(a.length * a[0].length)` will give you the size of all of the arrays in the array. You add the cast to `(double)` in the calculation of the average to avoid integer arithmetic problems (e.g., `25/6` is `4`).

Note that if the arrays are large enough, it is possible for `sum` to overflow.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer, so that future visitors will know that this answer helped you (comments can be deleted at any time).